# Intermediate Progress doesn't work with ActionBarSherlock running on Gingerbread

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I setup ActionBarSherlock with my app, and I'm trying to use the Intermediate Progress, I'm using this:

```
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);    
    setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
```

In my onCreate, and then using:

```
    setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

To enable it.

It works fine in ICS but it doesn't work at all in Gingerbread or Froyo, does anyone know how to get it to work? Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just had the same problem. Jake's solution above did not fix it for me - the method is undefined.

I found a working solution posted by Jake on the bug list for ActionBarSherlock here:

- [Action Bar Indeterminate Progress Bar Not Disappearing](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/actionbarsherlock/ixMX62VBcBY)

See Jake's response to the poster - the trick is to call `getSupportActionBar()` first, to "trigger creation of the views".

So my `onCreate()` method is:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0)
{
    super.onCreate(arg0);

    // allow window to show progress spinner in the action bar
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    getSupportActionBar();
    setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false); 
}
```

---

**Update based on comment from Laux:**

Make sure your imports reflect `com.actionbarsherlock.view.Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS` for this to work.

Here is part of my `import` block from an app that uses this pattern:

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.ActionProvider;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Window;
import com.actionbarsherlock.widget.ShareActionProvider;
```

This is a very good thing to remember when working with ABS - many of your normal Android imports should be updated to refer to ABS instead.

It may be a good idea to revisit your import block, or possibly remove it entirely and let Eclipse rebuild it for you (CTRL-SHIFT-O) to which point Eclipse will prompt you for each import that ABS redeclares.

This was also explained by Glebbb in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13740564/383414).

Comment: Additionally if still it doesn't work try to replace requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS); to  requestWindowFeature(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure you've probably figured it out by now, but the most likely culprit is you including the wrong file because it's so easy to do automatically.

Replace any import of **android.view.Window** with **com.actionbarsherlock.view.Window** and the needed features will work.

Comment: Thank you ! I've been looking for this for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `supportRequestWindowFeature`.

`requestWindowFeature` is a final method on `Activity` and couldn't be overriden.

Comment: If I use    supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS); It says that the method is undefined.

Comment: Looking at the available functions in a SherlockActivity there is:

`public final boolean requestWindowFeature (int featureId)` - which comes from the standard Android Activity

and 

`public final void `requestWindowFeature (long featureId)` - which comes from the SherlockActivity 

I cannot see a `supportRequestWindowFeature()` method.

Answer (score -1):

Check, if you are using `Theme.Sherlock.NoActionBar` or similar no action bar theme for this activity. 
In this case `setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility` method fails for me with

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.updateProgressBars(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:710)
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.onIntChanged(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:686)
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.updateInt(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:681)
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.setFeatureInt(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:665)
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:637)
at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:282)
```

I guess you should use a progress dialog instead to indicate loading process or regular `Theme` with activity title bar and then use `setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility` method for older platforms.