# ActionBarSherlock - Indeterminate Progress

Tags: android, android-actionbar

It's clear that for showing/hiding the indeterminate progress you have to use this method:

```
itemMenu.setActionView(...);
```

So:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_refresh:
            item.setActionView(R.layout.indeterminate_progress_action);
            runAsyncTask();
    ...
    }
}
```

What is not clear to me is: how to set the action view back to null. I don't want to keep a reference to a MenuItem, I don't think it is correct since I don't want to assume anything about the OptionsMenu lifecycle.

How should I set back the action view to null on onPostExecute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do it like this :

```
refresh = false; // the future state of your indeterminate progress
invalidateOptionsMenu(); // trigger the recreation of the menu and call onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu)
```

then in your onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) method :

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
{
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    MenuItem refreshItem = menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.action_bar_refresh, 1, "Refresh");
    refreshItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

    if(refresh)
        refreshItem.setActionView(R.layout.indeterminate_progress_action);
    else
        refreshItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_refresh);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about [`invalidateOptionsMenu()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu%28%29)? Your `onCreateOptionsMenu()` would probably always set it to `null`, then.

Comment: It could work. What do you think about refreshing the reference on onPrepareOptionsMenu ?

Comment: @gwa: If you mean setting it `null` there instead of `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, presumably that would work, though I don't know what you're gaining by that approach.

Comment: Still confused about it. I'll try to dig in more. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could just call `setActionView(null)` on that MenuItem

Then refresh the ActionBar with `invalidateOptionsMenu()`

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to manipulate specific menu items if you would prefer not to.

I use a different approach that leverages off the system's indeterminate progress bar functionality (as ported to ActionBarSherlock). I explain it here to offer more options to future readers to use whichever way works best for them.

---

My base fragment has a method I call to turn my loading UI on & off. Here is a trimmed down version:

```
private void setLoading(final boolean isLoading)
{
    final SherlockFragmentActivity sherlockActivity = getSherlockActivity();
    sherlockActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            // show loading progress bar
            sherlockActivity
                .setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(isLoading);

            // hide the rest of the menu
            setMenuVisibility(!isLoading);
        }
    });
}
```

---

For this to work, your activity must be configured to use the correct style - call this from your `SherlockFragmentActivity.onCreate()` method:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
```

---

The final trick is that on pre-HoneyComb devices, this causes the progress bar to show immediately by default (instead of being hidden by default from HC & above).

- you must set it to be invisible
- you must also create a Sherlock Action Bar instance before this code will work

The `onCreate()` thus becomes:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0)
{
    super.onCreate(arg0);

    // allow window to show progress spinner in the action bar
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    getSupportActionBar();
    setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false); 
}
```

---

For more details on this you can check my answer to

- [Intermediate Progress doesn't work with ActionBarSherlock running on Gingerbread (here).](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13247023/383414)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to keep a reference to the menu item, then you can simply keep a reference to the Menu object instead. A reference to the Menu is guaranteed to remain valid until the next time `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is called as mentioned in the docs ([http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29)).

Then call:

```
MenuItem menuItem = mMenu.findItem(R.id.favourite_payment);
menuItem.setActionView(null);
```

Or alternatively if using AppCompat:

```
MenuItem menuItem = mMenu.findItem(R.id.favourite_payment);
MenuItemCompat.setActionView(menuItem, null);
```

There is no need to call `invalidateOptionsMenu()`.